# How to detect which joystick pressed button?

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, joystick, gamepad

In Unity InputManager (Edit -> Project Settings -> Input) I can define and name different inputs. I have an event called "Draw" that happens when `joystick button 0` is pressed. This seems to be working. However, I cannot tell which controller pressed the button as the `Joy Num` option only works with axis and not with buttons. How to do that?

```
// How to tell which controller?
bool pressedDraw = Input.GetButtonDown("Draw");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same button on different joystick is defined as its own button, as documented [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html).

```
Joystick1Button0
Joystick2Button0
...
```

Answer (score 0):

joystick 1 button 0,
joystick 2 button 0
It has to be like this. Keeping it here for my self as well if I ever start looking for same question.
Go through all the numbers in a loop till 20 based on your joystick.
Log each button event so you know if it's pressed down. Easiest way to know which button is being pressed.